# Trouble Comparing Elements of Sets (Python)?

Tags: python, set, return, comparison

I'm working on a program in which I need to check each element of a set (from a list of sets) and compare it against a 'master' set and then append the set to a list if at least a single element of the two sets match.

I tried attacking this problem like a list only to realize that indexing doesn't work on sets.

Ex of what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
newlist = []
i = set([5, 3, 1]) # <-- 'Master' Set
z = set([5, 0, 4])

#Output should be -> newlist = [set([5,0,4])]
```

Comment: For future reference, the `set` documentation is [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset). (It doesn't come up on Google, unfortunately.)

Answer (score 1):

Assume `z` is list of *sets* like in your question description but not in your attached snippet.

```
newlist = [x for x in z if not i.isdisjoint(set(x))]
# or newlist = [x for x in z if i.intersection(set(x))]
```

[Live demo](http://ideone.com/K1ww2O)

Comment: `not x.isdisjoint(i)` lets you avoid creating an intersection set.

Comment: @user2357112 Thanks!

Comment: Hm... Returns AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'intersection'

Comment: @BrandonCharette: so you have *lists* is your list `z` then?

Comment: @BrandonCharette then 1. call `i.isdisjoint()` where `i` must be a `set` according to your description; 2. Convert temporary `x` into `set` all the time

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of intersection and set to solve this problem:

```
>>> s1 = set([1,2,3])
>>> s2 = set([3,4,5])
>>> s3 = set([6,7,8])
>>> len(s1.intersection(s2))
1
>>> len(s1.intersection(s3))
0
```

So basically, write an if statement to check the length of the intersection of the two sets. If length is greater than 0, make newlist equal to your second set.